# Specific Japanese/Foreign Language text not rendering in modern desktop browser(s)

Tags: firefox, unicode

I've recently come across an issue where some Japanese text on certain web pages won't render properly no matter what I do. I've tested many browsers, changed character encoding and even gone as far as changing the OS language and nothing fixes it. All the browser plugins are up-to-date and I've tried safe-mode in Firefox as well.

I've tried Firefox 3, Firefox 4 RC, IE 8, IE 9, Safari 5.0.4 on Windows 7, Mac OS X Snow Leopard, and Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat.

Interestingly enough though the page renders just fine in iOS 4.3's Safari.app on my 4G touch.

I note the fact that if it works on iOS it's definitely not Flash since iOS doesn't support Flash and I've disabled JavaScript in the Safari settings and it still works which leaves me thinking it has something to do with the HTML? Perhaps web standards?

An example link of this problem is here: http://utaten.com/lyric/jb71008071

Comment: This is a browser problem, not a problem with a specific web app. This is a question for [su] or, perhaps, [apple.se].

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely the font, most fonts simply don't have Japanese characters. If it renders in iOS, that's probably selecting a different font from the CSS than the others. If that's the case, just ensure all the fonts in the CSS list support Japanese.

Comment: How do I change the CSS font/check if the CSS list supports Japanese?

Comment: It is Flash, right click on it. iOS is obviously replacing the Flash with HTML. Embedding fonts into ActionScript is somewhat off-topic for this forum, I'm afraid.

Comment: I can't find anything in the Global Settings Manager that relates to fonts. Interestingly enough right-clicking "Settings..." doesn't do anything but right-clicking "Global Settings..." does.

Comment: If it helps here's a screen cap of what I see when it tries to render the page in Firefox 4: http://img.ly/images/775860/full